# Coldfusion 9 - Checkbox values from form to replace parameter value/s

Tags: loops, coldfusion

Very new to coldfusion. So I have a a form outputs values from DB into checkboxes.

```
<cfoutput query="Offices">
         <label><input type="checkbox" value="#offices#" name="Offices">#offices#</label>
</cfoutput>
```

and when a user selects more than one checkbox it passes multiple parameters into URL which looks like this:

```
offices.cfm?Offices=A&Offices=B&Offices=C
```

I am trying to prevent multiple of the same parameters being passed so I want it to return like:

```
offices.cfm?Offices=A,B,C&...
```

I am really struggling to figure this out. Help is appreciated.

Comment: *which looks like this:...* True, but that is just how they are transmitted via url.  If you dump the `#URL#` scope, you should see that CF has already parsed those values into a tidy csv list already. You can access that list using the variable name `URL.Offices`.

Comment: @Leigh your right. But to satisfy requirements is there way to pass comma delimited list of values like the cfdump has into that parameter?

Comment: If you use `method = "post"` in your form tag, the variables won't be in the address bar at all.  This is my preference.  Also, bear in mind that if no boxes are checked, the variable will not be defined.  You'll have to do something about that.

Comment: @DanBracuk I handled that part already, I would need these values in the URL because I have a feature where I capture the URL and give the user the ability to save their search.

Comment: (Edit) @Ren44 - Can you elaborate on why the construction of the url poses an issue? It is the standard way multiple fields with the same name are [passed via GET](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-data-set). I suppose you could use javascript to grab the checkbox values, build a csv string, and store that single value in a new field, but .. just wondering if that is really necessary.

Comment: @Leigh as weird as this seems, I am not actually sure. Team member said have it done this way. That is all. He gave me a good reason but I do not remember what he said.

Comment: (Edit) @Ren44 - I am curious what the "good reason" is ;-), but ... it can be done as I described above. However, all "successful" form controls are still be passed in the URL. Not sure if that is a deal-breaker without knowing why it must be done this way ...

Comment: @Leigh well after a lot of research, you were right. When I dump the url scope everything is already comma delimited. CF automatically just handles it this way.

Comment: @Ren44 - Yes, the end result it is not immediately obvious from the way values are transmitted. However, CF neatly parses everything into either a csv list, or arrays if you prefer (using the [application setting `sameformfieldsasarray`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/application-cfc-reference/application-variables.html).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Summary from comments, just to close out this thread ...)

True, but that is just how the parameters are transmitted in the url. Per the [html specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-data-set), when using method GET, the browser builds a builds a big string of name/value pairs for all (successful) form fields. Then appends them to the url as the query string:

> **Submit the encoded form data set**
>
> If the method is "get" and the action is an HTTP URI, the user agent takes the value of action, appends a `?` to it, 
>       then appends the form data set, encoded using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content type.
>
> **form data set**
>
> A form data set is a sequence of control-name/current-value *pairs* constructed from successful controls

However, it does not matter that the field name appears multiple times in the URL. If you dump the `#URL#` scope, you will see that CF has already parsed those values into a single CSV list for you. That list can be accessed using the variable name `URL.Offices`.